# What is the purpose of using separate key pairs for signing and encryption?

Tags: security, digital-signature, encryption-asymmetric

Why do I need to use separate public key pairs for signing and encryption
and not use the same key pair with RSA for example?
Is there any security problem with using the same key?

Comment: The question is better answered by [*Why should one not use the same asymmetric key for encryption as they do for signing?* - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/why-should-one-not-use-the-same-asymmetric-key-for-encryption-as-they-do-for-sig).

Answer (score 30):

The reason for using separate key pairs for signing and encryption is to spread the risk: If someone recovers the private encryption key, he/she can decrypt documents that were encrypted using the public encryption key but can’t use it to also sign documents and vice versa.

Another reason could be [a legal reason](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature#Using_separate_key_pairs_for_signing_and_encryption):

> In several countries, a digital signature has a status somewhat like that of a traditional pen and paper signature, like in the [EU digital signature legislation](http://europa.eu/legislation_summaries/information_society/l24118_en.htm). Generally, these provisions mean that anything digitally signed legally binds the signer of the document to the terms therein. For that reason, it is often thought best to use separate key pairs for encrypting and signing. Using the encryption key pair, a person can engage in an encrypted conversation (e.g., regarding a real estate transaction), but the encryption does not legally sign every message he sends. Only when both parties come to an agreement do they sign a contract with their signing keys, and only then are they legally bound by the terms of a specific document. After signing, the document can be sent over the encrypted link. If a signing key is lost or compromised, it can be revoked to mitigate any future transactions. If an encryption key is lost, a backup or key escrow should be utilized to continue viewing encrypted content. Signing keys should never be backed up or escrowed.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to have two signing key pairs, one for "I sent this message" (which would be useful during contract negotiations), and another one for "I want to be legally bound by this contract"?

Comment: disagree, one of the signatures is stating i do not wish to be legally bound. Which is an important distinction.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to go to see this similar question from the security stack :

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1806/why-should-one-not-use-the-same-asymmetric-key-for-encryption-as-they-do-for-sig

IMHO, the answer from Am1rr3zA is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Reasons for using separate keys for signing and encryption:

1. Useful in organization were encryption key needs to be backed or
   kept in escrow in order to decrypt data once an employee/user of the
   organization is no longer available. Unlike the encryption key the
   signing key must never be used by anyone other then the
   employee/user and does not and should not need to be kept in escrow.
2. Allows having different expiration times for signing an encryption
   keys.
3. Given that the underlying mathematics is the same for encryption and
   signing, only in reverse, if an attacker can convince/trick a key
   holder to sign an unformatted encrypted message using the same key
   then the attacker gets the original.

Comment: Note that #3 is RSA-specific. The underlying mathematics for signing and encrypting are typically different. RSA used without padding has the nasty property that a signing oracle will decrypt messages, but good signature and encryption schemes for RSA make sure that the operations are different (so you can't use a PSS-signing oracle to decrypt OEAP-encrypted messages).

Comment: You are likely correct (source?). Though I will leave the answer as is as it still answers the OP's question given that he/she mentioned RSA as an example and didn't ask for many other specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Having separate signing and encryption key pairs allows a company to back up the encryption certificate in order to decrypt data if you leave the company and they find stuff encrypted with your key.

Typically, the company won't keep a backup copy of your signing certificate, since it would destroy the notion of a valid digital signature.  If the signing certificate is held by more than one party, then who really signed a message with it?

So, encryption key is held by the user and backed up by the company.  Signing key is only held by the user.

Comment: @nKn To me this looks like an answer, not a question. The question itself is probably too broad and opinion-based by today's standards and would be closed if it were new, but given the question, this is an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are getting at. I am going to assume you want to know why you should use different keys for https/ssl/ssh and code signing (other than that they have different usage bits).

SSL certificates have to hang out around web servers, which are infamous for being compromised. Code signing certificates can be hidden away completely offline. In theory. In practice web servers are managed by professional sysadmins, and code signing certs are left lying around on bodge-a-job developer PCs. Also there's the Principle of Least Privilege.

Answer (score -9):

Read this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

Basically you are asking about the different between asymmetric and symmetric encryption.

Comment: I understand the question to be about why using different keypairs for (assymetric) encryption and (also assymetric) signing. In principle my public signing key could work for sending encrypted messages to me, too.

Comment: ... then there is no point of having a public & private key. The whole idea is having 2 keys, one should encrypt and one should decrypt. If the same key does that then it's pointless to have using assymetric enc. I think I still didn't get what you are trying to ask.

Comment: (It was not me asking here.) The way public key cryptography works:  `cryptotext = crypt(message, public_key); message = crypt(cryptotext, private_key)`. Public key signing: `signature = crypt(message, private_key); message = crypt(signature, public_key)` (with `message` being usually a hash of the document). Where is the reason to use another key **pair** for the first two operations than for the last two?